# Hash All Files in a Folder

Tags: files

Is there an app to hash all files inside a folder? I'd like to have a text list like the one you get if you go into a directory in Linux and execute

```
sha256sum *
```

I always use sha256, but here I don't really care as long as it's a standard hash algorithm. md5 is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi! Questions such as "*Is there an app that does X*" are off-topic here. Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic here. However, [softwarerecs.se] is the fitting place for such questions, provided that you follow their on-topic [guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File Hash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fileHash.pkg) by Light Weight Apps lets you calculate the md5 hash of all the files in a chosen directory. It may be frustrating because you have to copy the text generated by hand. It seems like there is no 'save' function.

Comment: The link doesn't work. It's like 2 links mixed together.

Comment: Here you can find the apk file http://apk-dl.com/file-hash

Comment: Download didn't work on my PC (out of download contingent) and redirected me to a scam site on my phone but the application can be found as `File Hash` in the Google Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fileHash.pkg